# Points on a CorePlot graph

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, graphics, core-plot

I'm working on graphics with CorePlot, and I had this graph on my app:

[The graphic I have http://data.imagup.com/10/1159174088.3134png](http://data.imagup.com/10/1159174088.3134png)

Now I need the coordinates to be marked as points, something like this:

[The graphic I want http://data.imagup.com/12/1159172987.1122png](http://data.imagup.com/12/1159172987.1122png)

What do I have to add to have it?

Thank you

Comment: Are you setting the plotSymbol?

Comment: [boundLinePlot setPlotSymbol: (I don't know what to put here)]; I search the net about CorePlot doc, but I didn't find anything. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this..

```
// Add the plot symbol.
CPTPlotSymbol *plotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol]; // Ellipse is used for circles
plotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor]];
plotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0);

// Set the line style of the edges of your symbol. (Around your symbol)
CPTMutableLineStyle *plotSymbolLineStyle = [[[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc] init] autorelease];
plotSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
plotSymbolLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
plotSymbol.lineStyle = plotSymbolLineStyle;

plot.plotSymbol = plotSymbol;
```

(`plot` could be e.g. a `CPTScatterPlot`)

From here it should be easy to modify the symbol as you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly, now what I'm asking you, please, where did you learn that CorePlot, because I don't want, every time to come and ask questions that can be very easy. ;)

Comment: @zak: Whenever there are something I don't know how to do, I usually check the documentation, or the examples that come with Core Plot. If I still haven't found anything, I do some searching on SO and Google. I've learned most from studying the examples.

Comment: where did you find that exemples or that doc? bye the way, do you know  how to make the origin of the coordinates fixed (immobile)?

Comment: @zak: the docs and the examples (with code) are on the Core Plot home page. You should check them out. :-) For your other question: take a look at axis constraints. (See the `axisConstraints` property of the `CPTAxis` class. If you have any questions related to this, you should probably create another question, or do some searching.)